# Congratulations bobble for raising 1000 helpful flags!

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

If you're an active PSE user, you'll know that [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble) is an active moderator *(merely without a diamond)*. Just recently she reached 1000 helpful flags... which is quite a feat given her time on PSE *(<2 years)* and the size of PSE *(pretty small compared to sites like SO)*.

We mustn't forget, [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) has almost 3K helpful flags... the most among all the users *(with bobble coming in second)*! Great work cleaning up our site ;)

Comment: And sorry mods for raising so many NLNs!